# Web scraping with Python3, and string formatting ?

Tags: python, json, google-chrome, currency

this script is meant to parse Bloomberg finance to find the GBP value during the day, this following script does that however when it returns you get this:

{'dateTime': '2017-01-17T22:00:00Z', 'value': 1.6406}

I don't want the dateTime, or the value text there. I don't know how to get rid of it. and when I try it gives me errors like this: list index out of range.

any answers will be greatly appreciated. here is the script (in python3):

```
import urllib.request
import json 

htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-       time-series/price/GBPAUD%3ACUR?timeFrame=1_DAY').read().decode('utf8')  

data = json.loads(htmltext)  

datapoints = data[1]['price'] 

print(datapoints)
```

Comment: First of all, the example data you provided does not contain `price`, so that should throw you an exception. Also `dict` objects are not indexable, meaning you can't do `[1]`. Try, `print(data['value'])`. Basically JSON data is nearly identical to what python calls [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) - And they are not indexable, they're accessed via the key value, in your example above that would be either `'dateTime'` or `'value'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
print (data[0]['price'][-1]['value'])
```

**EDIT:** To get all the values,

```
for data_row in data[0]['price']:
    print data_row['value']
```

**EXPLANATION**: `data[0]` gets the first and only element of the list, which is a dict. 
   `['price']` gets the list corresponding to the price key. 
 `[-1]` gets the last element of the list, which is presumably the data you'll be looking for as it's the latest data point.

 Finally, `['value']` gets the value of the currency conversion from the dict we obtained earlier.

Comment: how would i get all elements ?

Comment: when i try that for the dateTime value, i get an error which reads 'TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable'. What does this mean? and can you help me with it ?